# Leap Motion in Unreal Engine works well until I package the game where it won't track anything

Tags: plugins, unreal-engine4, motion, leap-motion

Using Unreal Engine 4.19.2 with Leap Motion plugin 2.17.1 for UE.

I'm using the default LeapHandsPawn included, and it works in game VR-preview, no problems at all, but as soon as I package the project and try the exe, the hands are missing, won't track at all.

### Edit

I found the hands! They're stuck in the floor and won't track!

Doesn't seem to be a issue with the Leap Motion, rather the Unreal Engine project, am I building it wrong? Do I need to include something to get the hands to track in my packaged game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It appears that if you're using custom plugins like LeapMotion you need to add a C++ Class to your game before you package it, otherwise it won't work when packaging.